# Oracle Update Join based on a select

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Using the following select and want to do an update, but finding the syntax a bit confusing, so much easier in Microsoft SQL!

The select is the below and what I want to do is base on this select anything where c.allow_to_trade = 'Y' to 'N' and the rest of the criteria.

```
SELECT MAX(Trade_date) "TRADE DATE",
  t.client,
  c.shortened_name,
  c.allow_to_trade "ACTIVE",
  C.GCD_NUMBER
FROM lib.trades t ,
  lib.client_address c
WHERE t.client       = c.client
AND c.allow_to_trade = 'Y'
GROUP BY C.GCD_NUMBER,
  t.client,
  c.shortened_name,
  c.allow_to_trade
HAVING MAX(trade_date) < '01-may-2012'
```

thanks in advance

Comment: It is not very clear what you want to do. Your query gives an aggregate data, so you can not update it. Do you want to update all the clients which are returned by this query?

Comment: Yes- Anything that is returned by that query I want to set the allow_to_trade to 'N'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can, you, please try this:

```
UPDATE lib.client_address
SET allow_to_trade='N'
WHERE client IN
  (SELECT t.client
  FROM lib.trades t ,
    lib.client_address c
  WHERE t.client       = c.client
  AND c.allow_to_trade = 'Y'
  GROUP BY C.GCD_NUMBER,
    t.client,
    c.shortened_name,
    c.allow_to_trade
  HAVING MAX(trade_date) < '01-may-2012'
  );
```

Comment: after I changed client_address to lib.client_address it worked! thanks

Comment: You are welcome! Is your table's name is address or client_address?